# Access to an array element using a variable stored in it's structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct, hashtable, lookup-tables

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;

struct Foo{
 int bar;
 int var2; //etc...
};

Foo array[1000];

int main(){
    int var;
    while(var < 1000)
    {
        array[var].bar = //an unique number
        var++;
    }
}
```

Let's suppose a I have a code like that. In each element of the array, there is a variable with an unique number `(bar)`. Now, I want to use this number to access to the entire element (and maybe manipulate it's other variables). How can I do that ?

Comment: `int var;` is uninitialized before `while(var < 1000)`. Your compiler should be screaming at you.

Comment: `array[var].var2 = 12;` or am I missing something?

Comment: You need a hashtable with key `bar`.

Comment: Without a hash table, you will have to search each struct in `array` to find the unique `bar` you are looking for and then access the other members of that element-struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In each element of the array, there is a variable with an unique
>   number `(bar)`.

This can be quite easily achieved since you have control over your unique keys.
If you arrange your array to have keys in the sorted order, you can use the C library function `bsearch` for fast lookups.

(Note: please initialize `int var;` in your code.)

> Now I want to use this number to access to the entire  element (and
>   maybe manipulate it's other variables)

This can be as simple as specifying a key for function `get_foo`:

```
Foo *obj =  get_foo(3);
```

Simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5
typedef struct Foo Foo;

struct Foo{
    int bar;  // key
    int var2; // etc...
    int var3; // etc...
};

Foo array[ARRAY_SIZE];

static int compare_keys(const void *va, const void *vb) {
    const Foo *a = va, *b = vb;
    return (a->bar -  b->bar);
}

Foo * get_foo(int key) {
    Foo *foo = bsearch(&key, array, sizeof array / sizeof array[0],
        sizeof array[0], compare_keys);
    return foo; 
}

int main(void){
    int var = 0;

    while(var < ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        array[var].bar =    var;     // an unique key number 
        array[var].var2 = 2*var;     // some data
        array[var].var3 = 3*var;     // some data
        var++;
    }

    // The array of structures should be sorted by the value of the unique key 
    // verification that we can look up all the valid keys.
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof array[0]; ++i) {
        Foo * v = get_foo(array[i].bar);

        if(v)
            printf("key: %3d ->  values:  %2d,  %3d\n", array[i].bar, v->var2, v->var3 );
        else
           printf("Key not found %2d \n", array[i].bar); 
    } 

    // finding a particular object is simple:
    printf("\nFind object for key = %2d \n", 3); 
    Foo *obj =  get_foo(3);
    if(obj)
        printf("key: %3d ->  values:  %2d,  %3d\n", 3, obj->var2, obj->var3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
key:   0 ->  values:   0,    0                                                                                                                 
key:   1 ->  values:   2,    3                                                                                                                 
key:   2 ->  values:   4,    6                                                                                                                 
key:   3 ->  values:   6,    9                                                                                                                 
key:   4 ->  values:   8,   12                                                                                                                 

Find object for key =  3                                                                                                                       
key:   3 ->  values:   6,    9
```